# Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307) for local files

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have a project with all the files under 'src'.

Used the below rule to disable relative imports:

```
"no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
        "patterns": ["./*"]
        }  
      ]
```

And now I'm getting ts2307 for all local imports from within the same folder:

```
import card from 'card';
```

While relative path works, but I don't want to use relative paths, and no-restricted-imports complains about it (intended)

```
import card from './card';
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Which other configurations can I check to get rid of the ts2307?

Comment: Have you tried with `"patterns": [".*"]`?

Comment: @GOTO0 yes, but it doesn't help, error is the same.